# Why does λz.zq reduce to q?

Tags: lambda-calculus

The way I see it, it should not be further reducible. I'm thinking `λz.zq` is like

```
lambda z: z(q) # Python, not lambda calc
```

and you do not know z nor q so it is not further reducible.

The below derivation (where I am wondering about the last steps) is from the new [Haskell book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGqv4.png):

[image]

Comment: [beta-reduction (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B2-reduction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [$\beta$-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B2-reduction) defined in terms of substitution (rename [($\alpha$-conversion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion) first if necessary):

$$(\lambda z. zq) (q) \to_{\beta} [z/q](zq) = qq. $$

---

In Haskell, $\lambda z.zq$ defines an anonymous function which takes a single parameter (represented by $z$) and performes $zq$.

Comment: Now that I understand the mechanics of lambda calc better I see that this was just a straightforward application of the rules. Thanks though.